# How Do I Resolve Concurrency Violations with DataTables in .NET?

Tags: .net, database, concurrency

I'm using DataTables in VB.NET 2.0, and I'm writing code to handle the concurrency violations I expect to occur in a multi-user environment. I understand how to trap concurrency violations, but I don't understand how to resolve them while using the DbCommandBuilder-generated INSERT, UPDATE, and DELETE commands.

It seems to me that concurrency violations occur in five different situations:

When...

1. Updating a row that has been concurrently updated in the database
2. Updating a row that has been concurrently deleted from the database
3. Deleting a row that has been concurrently updated in the database
4. Deleting a row that has been concurrently deleted from the database
5. Inserting a row whose primary key has been concurrently inserted into the database

I know how to resolve situation 1; I've found several examples of how to use the DataTable.Merge method to synchronize updated rows. However, Merge doesn't seem to work for the other 4 situations.

As an example, suppose I'm trying to update a row that has been concurrently deleted from the database (situation 2), and my business rules tell me to restore the row into the database with the updated column values. I can't figure out how to change the DataRow properties so that the Adapter.Update method will insert the row into the database as required; Merge doesn't do it.

Given the ease with which Merge handles situation 1, I'm certain there must be simple resolutions to the other concurrency violations as well, and I've just overlooked them. Can anyone provide me with a nudge in the right direction?

-TC

Answer (score 0):

If the row you are trying to update was deleted by another process, and you need to restore it, then you need to catch the concurrency exception that occurs when you try to update and respond by inserting the row back into the database:

1. Save the updated values.
2. Merge the concurrency violations into your table, which will delete the row that was deleted in the database.
3. Insert a new row into your table with the saved values.
4. Save the table.

Comment: David, Thank you for the reply. Unfortunately, I find that step 2 does not work as you describe. When I merge concurrency violations into my table, the rows that were deleted from the database do not get deleted from the DataTable.

Comment: Also, you mention that this should be done in response to a concurrency exception. However, I find that concurrency exceptions are raised for one violation at a time, while merging must be done for the entire table at once. Therefore, handling violations at the time exceptions are raised allows the possibility that a second or third violation will be handled incorrectly. Because of this, I've concluded that concurrency exceptions cannot be relied up to initiate the response, and I must preemptively hunt for violations. Am I mistaken?